# How to calculate new column with sum of moving time window within a group in snwoflake SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, moving-average

I have a table like this:

| date | ID | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 24 |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 10 |
| 2021-01-03 | A | 5 |
| 2021-01-04 | A | 1 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 5 |
| 2021-01-02 | B | 10 |
| 2021-01-03 | B | 1 |
| 2021-01-04 | B | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 5 |
| 2021-01-03 | C | 10 |
| 2021-01-04 | C | 1 |
| 2021-01-05 | C | 10 |

and I want to calculate a new column that sums the count value for the two days before the date within each ID. There might be missing dates (days) in between, which is why a simple lag function propably will not work (See example ID C). So I want to sum the values in between a certain date range within each ID.

So the resulting table should look like

| date | ID | count | sum_two_days_before |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 24 | Null |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 10 | Null |
| 2021-01-03 | A | 5 | 34 |
| 2021-01-04 | A | 1 | 15 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 5 | Null |
| 2021-01-02 | B | 10 | Null |
| 2021-01-03 | B | 1 | 15 |
| 2021-01-04 | B | 10 | 11 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 5 | Null |
| 2021-01-03 | C | 10 | 5 |
| 2021-01-04 | C | 1 | 10 |
| 2021-01-05 | C | 10 | 11 |

Would be glad about help!

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: `SELECT CURRENT_VERSION();` returns 6.0.0

Comment: so the data spec seems fishy, because it saying if I have lots of history (2+ prior days) any of the prior days are valid, but if I only have one prior day, its only valid if it 2 days old.

Answer (score 0):

A correlated sub-query might work.
But can't verify.

```
SELECT *
, (  SELECT SUM(t2.count) 
     FROM your_table t2 
     WHERE t2.ID = t.ID
       AND t2.date IN (DATEADD(day,-1,t.date), DATEADD(day,-2,t.date))
     HAVING COUNT(t2.date) = 2
  ) AS sum_two_days_before
FROM your_table t
ORDER BY t.ID, t.date;
```

And if that doesn't work.
Maybe adding 2 [LAG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/lag.html) will work.
But it just looks for previous days, not today-1 & today-2

```
SELECT *
, LAG(t.count, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.date) +
  LAG(t.count, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID ORDER BY t.date) AS sum_two_dates_before
FROM your_table t
ORDER BY t.ID, t.date;
```

But if snowlake isn't having the `HAVING`, then maybe this will work.

```
SELECT *
, (  SELECT 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.date = DATEADD(day,-2,t.date) THEN t2.count END) 
     + SUM(CASE WHEN t.date = DATEADD(day,-1,t.date) THEN t2.count END) 
     FROM your_table t2 
     WHERE t2.ID = t.ID
       AND t2.date IN (DATEADD(day,-1,t.date), DATEADD(day,-2,t.date))
  ) AS sum_two_days_before
FROM your_table t
ORDER BY t.ID, t.date;
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost does the job! Besides that `having` is not working and that the result does not have `NULL` values for those rows which do not have 2 previous days.

Comment: Well, I don't have access to a snowflake. So it was a shot in the dark with a query that would work in most databases. But really, it's having a problem with having? Oh well.

Comment: @FAMG Does the 2nd solution work?

Comment: @FAMG Does the 3th solution help?

Comment: Thank you so much @LukStorms! The second option does not work, due to the fact that there might be missing dates, so a fixed lag would then add up days which should not be sumed (e.g. ID C 01.01. and 03.01). The third option unfortunately is not supported by snowflake. But option 1 without the having almost did it and I can live with it. So thanks a lot!

Comment: The second solution does not work because `+` between `10 + null` = `null`, and if you swap in some form of NVL, then you get an 0 for the first answer row.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Getting the NULL's for when there's no today-2 is intentional. See expected result.

Comment: So you are correct. Last two days hmm. Will have to rethink this one.. your second example gives `null` for the `2021-01-03 C`, because you are in row space, not date space.

Answer (score 0):

So correct "as described" results can be gotten from a verbose version:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * FROM values 
('2021-01-01','A',  24, null),
('2021-01-02','A',  10, null),
('2021-01-03','A',  5, 34),
('2021-01-04','A',  1, 15),
('2021-01-01','B',  5, null),
('2021-01-02','B',  10, null),
('2021-01-03','B',  1, 15),
('2021-01-04','B',  10, 11),
('2021-01-01','C',  5, null),
('2021-01-03','C',  10, 5),
('2021-01-04','C',  1, 10),
('2021-01-05','C',  10, 11)
  v(date, id, count, expected )
)
SELECT
    date,
    id,
    count,
    expected,
    sum_2_days
FROM (
    SELECT
        date,
        id,
        count,
        expected,
        LAG(date,2)over(partition by id order by date) as d2,
        LAG(date,1)over(partition by id order by date) as d1,
        lag(count,2)over(partition by id order by date) as c2,
        lag(count,1)over(partition by id order by date) as c1,

        dateadd(day,-2,date)::date AS dm2,

        d2 is not null OR d1 = dm2 as X1,
        iff(d2 >= dm2, c2, 0) as x1_v2,
        iff(d1 >= dm2, c1, 0) as x1_v1,
        x1_v2 + x1_v1 as x1_r,
        iff(X1, x1_r, null) as sum_2_days
    FROM data
)
order by 2,1;
```

giving:

| DATE | ID | COUNT | EXPECTED | SUM_2_DAYS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 24 |  |  |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 10 |  |  |
| 2021-01-03 | A | 5 | 34 | 34 |
| 2021-01-04 | A | 1 | 15 | 15 |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 5 |  |  |
| 2021-01-02 | B | 10 |  |  |
| 2021-01-03 | B | 1 | 15 | 15 |
| 2021-01-04 | B | 10 | 11 | 11 |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 5 |  |  |
| 2021-01-03 | C | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| 2021-01-04 | C | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-01-05 | C | 10 | 11 | 11 |

or the compressed version:

```
SELECT
    date,
    id,
    count,
    expected,
    iff( LAG(date,2)over(partition by id order by date) is not null 
            OR LAG(date,1)over(partition by id order by date) = dateadd(day,-2,date)
         , iff( LAG(date,2)over(partition by id order by date) >= dateadd(day,-2,date)
                ,lag(count,2)over(partition by id order by date)
                ,0) 
           + iff( LAG(date,1)over(partition by id order by date) >= dateadd(day,-2,date)
                ,lag(count,1)over(partition by id order by date)
                ,0)
         ,null) as sum_2_days
FROM data
order by 2,1;
```

AND if you really want to do it with a double join you can via some pre-conditioning:

```
WITH date_a AS (
    SELECT date, id, count, expected, 
        dateadd(day,-2,date) as dm2, 
        first_value(date)over(partition by id order by date) as fd
    FROM data
)
select 
    a.date,
    a.id,
    a.count,
    a.expected,
    sum(iff(a.fd <= a.dm2, b.count, null)) as sum_2_days
FROM date_a a
LEFT JOIN data b
    ON a.id = b.id AND a.date > b.date AND b.date >= a.dm2
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
order by 2,1;
```